# Using virtual frame buffer fails when spawning child processes

Tags: xvfb

I'm trying to use Google Compute Engine for a machine learning project using python game that requires a GUI. Up to now, I've been using XVFB to make up for the fact that there's no GUI. I started it up using the commands

```
Xvfb :99 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

I've been modifying the game to use multithreading, but when I try to run the game, it fails giving error messages like

`XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":99"
      after 108 requests (108 known processed) with 0 events remaining.`

Anyone ever encounter a problem like this?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, when putting some process in background. Have you found a solution?